# grep on another file through piped output from one file

Tags: file, awk, grep, pipe

I am implementing a command

```
 awk '{if($2 == "1")print $1}' file1
```

the output of which , I would like to pipe to grep on another file, 
something like

```
 awk '{if($2 == "1")print $1}' file1 | grep to file2
```

However I am unaware of such method existing to pipe a grep to another file, any help would be helpful. Thanks

My file1 looks like this

```
 ENSG00000127527:I11 0
 ENSG00000086015:I6 0
 ENSG00000198336:I7 0
 ENSG00000127527:I12 0
 ENSG00000086015:I7 0
 ENSG00000198342:I1 0
 ENSG00000127527:I13 0
 ENSG00000086015:I8 0
 ENSG00000198342:I2 0
```

and my file 2 is as follows:

```
 chrX   99892102    99893102    ENSG00000000003:I1  -
 chrX   99890744    99890965    ENSG00000000003:I2  -
 chrX   99890250    99890402    ENSG00000000003:I3  -
 chrX   99889027    99890027    ENSG00000000003:I4  -
 chrX   99888537    99888732    ENSG00000000003:I5  -
 chrX   99887566    99887983    ENSG00000000003:I6  -
 chrX   99885864    99886864    ENSG00000000003:I7  -
 chrX   99840145    99840227    ENSG00000000005:I1  +
 chrX   99847620    99848620    ENSG00000000005:I2  +
 chrX   99849145    99849257    ENSG00000000005:I3  +
```

Comment: A good question will have a 1. small set of sample data, 2. expected output from that input,  3. current code/output/error msgs and 4. your thoughts about why things aren't working. Please re-read , http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and maybe the http://stackoverflow.com/tour Good luck.

Comment: What relationship to the multiple `$1`'s have? i.e., are they alternatives words or what? You need examples.

Comment: We'd just be guessing at what you mean by `I would like to pipe to grep on another file` since whatever you mean by that is apparently something you can't do. You need to post some concise, testable sample input and expected output to help clarify your requirements.

Comment: Can you add what you think is a match between those two files? They look like 100% no match to me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is extremely unclear.

However, you can use `awk` to grep the lines in the first file against the lines in the second.

Given:

```
$ cat f1.txt
Apple 1
Pear 1
Tomato 2
Potato 2
Cherry 1
$cat f2.txt
Apple 
Pear 
Tomato 
Potato 
Cherry
```

You can do a `grep` like pass against the second file with lines in the first like so:

```
awk 'NR==FNR && $2==1 {arr[$1]; next} # NR==FNR first file? save $1
     $1 in arr   # arr in f1 filtered by $2; print if match
 ' f1.txt f2.txt
Apple 
Pear 
Cherry
```

The line `$1 in arr` triggers the default action of print when true.

Comment: Can you please explain this command for beginners at awk?

Answer (score 5):

[dawg's `awk`-only answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41928001/45375) may be all you need, but to address your question as posed:

Your question appears to be: *how can I pass a command's output as the list of search terms to a `grep` call*?

You're asking about passing the output by *pipeline*, which, however, only works if the input to search *in* is not also passed to `grep` via stdin (which is how any command receives pipeline input).

Given that your `grep` command uses an actual *file* as its input (to search *in*) - `file2` -  a pipeline *is* an option:

```
awk '{if($2 == "1")print $1}' file1 | grep -f /dev/stdin file2
```

`grep`'s `-f` option accepts the search terms as a *file* (to which OR logic is implied: any input line that matches *any* of the lines in the search-terms file is considered a match), and by using `/dev/stdin` as the filename, `awk`'s output is used as the file's content.

Note: With *GNU* `grep`, you could also use `-` instead of `/dev/stdin`, but BSD/macOS `grep` doesn't support that.

---

The following solutions work irrespective of whether the input to search *in* is itself passed via stdin or not:

In `bash`, `ksh`, and `zsh`, the simplest way to provide a command's output as if it were a file is to use a [process substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution) (`<(...)`):

```
grep -f <(awk '{if($2 == "1")print $1}' file1) file2
```

That said, in the case at hand, where `grep` presumably has to read the entire file passed to `-f` into memory first anyway, the following POSIX-compliant equivalent, which uses a [command substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution) (`$(...)`), works just as well:

```
grep "$(awk '{if($2 == "1")print $1}' file1)" file2
```

However, the latter form runs the (hypothetical) risk of exceeding the platform's maximum command-line length, while the former does not.